# How to code a binary variable for "at least one of a set of a binary variables is one"

Tags: spss, binary-data

I have a (basic) question about recoding some variables that I have in an SPSS file. I am an Honours student and I am looking at students' use of study drugs as part of my thesis. In my survey I have a number of drugs and I would like to create a binary variable (1= User, 0=NonUser) based on whether an individual has used ANY of the drugs in my list. That is, I have a list of about 20 drugs, and if the individual has used one or more of them, I'd like their score to be 1 in the new variable. If the individual hasn't used any of the drugs I'd like them to score a 0 in this variable.

I'm sure that there is a way to do this quickly, but I've had no success in the "Recode into Different Variable" command.

Comment: Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to see the scope of our site. Questions purely about programming or coding are generally off-topic here. I think your question has an underlying statistical or mathematical aspect, though, in the sense that an appropriate mathematical formula will (so long as you know how to use the "Recode" command) let you get what you want. It may help if you can edit it to be less specific to SPSS.

Comment: If you have three binary variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and you want a new binary variable $y$ to be one if *at least one of the $x_i$ is one* then you can set $y = \max (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a fast way. you need to use the COUNT command in SPPS.

Given:
anydrug= is the new variable indicating if the respondent has got any of the drugs

drug 1= the first drug on your variable list

drug n= the last drug on your variable list

make sure you have all the drug variables in your list in sequence... example drug 1, drug2,....drugn and 1 indicated that drug is taken.

# this will count the number of drugs every respondents taken

COUNT anydrug= Drug1 To  Drugn(1).

Execute.

then

RECODE anydrug(0=0)(1 thru highest=1).

execute.

hope this helps :)

Comment: The ANY function will do this directly.